# what do I need to ask in the registration page for the log in. in asp using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic, security

what kind of questions do I need to ask. Also, I don't want everyone to have the ability to create an account so how can I distinguish the people that i want to give them the ability to create an account? 
In my login page i asked about username, password, email address, and a full name. also, in this case every body will have the ability to create an account. what i really want is let certain people to have ability to create an account, just certain people.

please if something not clear just ask me again or help me with it. I am new and so fresh to work by myself so any help will mean a lot to me. thanks

Comment: possibly the most open question ever asked on this website. What type of app? How are we to know who you want and who you don't? What kind of information do you want/need from a user?

Comment: Iam asking about common question to distinguish the who is the user. Thanks for marking me down!!!!!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about technical issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this site http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc964293.aspx and they perfectly explain how to create your login page.

Comment: Link only answers are not welcome in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you don't NEED to ask any. You could simply auto-generate a username and password combination and give it to the user.

Comment: Ok cool thanks and could you lead me how to auto-generate. Or just tell from where?